# How would a chain specification for a beacon chain look like?

Tags: testnets, genesis, eth-2.0, beacon-chain, chainspec

Do Ethereum 2.0 clients, such as Lighthouse, Nimbus, or Prysm implement any standard on defining different chain specifications or genesis blocks comparable to how legacy Ethereum clients do?

Would it be possible to bootstrap new beacon-chain testnets based on a specification file fed into the beacon-chain client implementations? If so, how?

I came across the following [configs/ in the eth-2.0-specs](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/configs/) but I'm not sure whether they serve as specification or actual client configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, they sure do! You can find a bunch of published specifications here:

https://github.com/eth2-clients/eth2-testnets

They are indeed based upon the "configs/ in the eth-2.0-spec" link you provided.